# Android Studio - Kotlin: Import Button

Tags: android, kotlin, button, import

I know this is probably a quite simple question to answer but I want to import my button from activity_main.xml with the id "button1":

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In the MainActivity.kt so I can add a setOnClickListener to it.
I saw something like this:
MainActivity.kt:

```
val button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button
```

That gives me 2 errors:
unresolved reference: findViewById;
unresolved reference: Button;
This is the action I want to add:

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

So I could use the setOnClickListener on "button1" but it wont work.
Whats the standard way of importing a button with kotlin so I can use it properly?

Comment: `but it wont work.` can you tell us what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, I needed to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

to the build.gradle (Module:app).
After that I was able to import all views via

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

on the MainActivity.kt so I could use the setOnClickListener to the Id I gave the button in the activity_main.xml

I think the findViewById() is just another way to do this, still good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Could Do This:

```
 val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, make sure that the Button and findViewById both were referenced from Activity class.

There are different ways for view binding. The recommended one is to use either data binding or view binding feature.

Kotlin synthetics, part of Android Kotlin Extensions Gradle  plugin, is Kotlin only method of view binding which doesn't expose nullabilty. That means all the views are declared as platform types. Now beginning from Kotlin 1.4.20, they will not be supported. Check migration to view binding here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

findVewbyId is another way for the same purpose, but this comes with some expenses like traversing the view hierarchy to get the view, runtime exceptions, boilerplate code.

Other way is to use library like ButterKnife